# How would you go about calculating the price of, say, upgrades that require you to have a previous upgrade? - javascript/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say you have a game with different upgrades that build on each other. For example, upgrade #2 would require you to have upgrade #1 before you upgrade to #2. Let's say upgrade #1 costs $1, upgrade #2 costs $2, and so on. If someone asked you how much you have paid for upgrades if you had upgrade #3, it would be $3 + $2 + $1. In Javascript, how would you calculate the total price given the upgrade that you currently have? I know you can just brute force it with a bunch of if statements or possibly a switch statement, but I feel like there has to be an easier way to do it.

A possible way to do it with a switch statement would look something like this:

```js
prices = {
  upgrade_3: 3
  upgrade_2: 2
  upgrade_1: 1
}
switch (upgrade) {
  case upgrade_1:
    return prices.upgrade_1
  case upgrade_2:
    return prices.upgrade_1 + prices.upgrade_2
  case upgrade_3:
    return prices.upgrade_1 + prices.upgrade_2 + prices.upgrade_3
  default:
    return 0
}
```

Comment: There's always going to be a 2-D array involved here, right?  One axis is "what version I have", the other axis is "what version I want", and the crossing is the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an array and a loop.

```
var prices = [];
prices[0] = 0; // base price
prices[1] = 1:
prices[2] = 2;
prices[3] = 3;

var currentlevel = 3;
var currentprice = 0;

for (var level = 0;level<=currentlevel;level++) {
  currentprice += prices[level];
}

//currentprice = 6;
```